# Only getting the 3 first elements in template

Tags: django, django-templates

```
{% for message in lab.email_sent_history.all %}
```

This gets all the messages. I know it's possible to only get the first three ones like this:

```
{% for message in lab.email_sent_history.all|slice:":3" %}
```

But I don't think this is a good idea since it first gets all the messages and then only keeps the three first. How can I only get the three first? Which is better from an optimization view.

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't think this is a good idea since it first gets all the messages and then only keeps the three first.

Not quite.

Slicing a queryset adds a `LIMIT` clause to the SQL query, which causes the database to limit the number of records returned. There is no need to optimize the template further.